# cancelAnimationFrame after timeout

Tags: javascript, animation, requestanimationframe

Id like a requestAnimationFrame based animation loop, stopping after x ms. I tried to implement this via a setTimeout that removes the cb after x. However, since setTimeout is about the last thing called in the event loop, *sometimes* one more frame of the animation gets rendered before the removal gets called.

Even though the delta (where it should be already canceled but isnt) is always very small, this messes up my iteration logic. The last animationFrame called **must** be within the given timeframe x.

I would really like to **not** check in every loop if the maximum has been exceeded yet.

Is there some sort of high priority setTimeout? Based on promises maybe?

Comment: Can you post your code? It's not *entirely* clear, it's difficult to debug code we can't see

Comment: @CertainPerformance sure, https://github.com/maximilianMairinger/animation-frame-delta/blob/master/app/src/animationFrameDelta.ts. Though I think this is mostly fog around the issue

Comment: *I would really like to not check in every loop if the maximum has been exceeded yet* - then you want the javascript engine to guess what you want for you? That's not how programming works

Comment: by the way, in most browsers `setTimeout` has deliberate *jitter* added, so, don't expect *ms* accuracy with setTimeout

Comment: @JaromandaX I dont quite get what you are trying to say. I would like to have an function added to an array for x ms. Within x time, it gets picked up by a requestAnimationFrame loop. I am asking for a consistant way to remove the function from the array. I am aware that setTimeout has some issues with beeing called consistantly after x. I assume this is because it has less priority in the event loop that requestAnimationFrame, hence I was wondering if there is another possibility to call a function after x time (with higher priority).

Comment: @JaromandaX I would like to not check every iteration if the time has passed, because I am somewhat performance concerned. I am aware of the possibility to simply check every time if the duration has passed, though I am trying to find a better performing implementation.

Comment: as I said, setTimeout has built in inaccuracy these days - so your best bet is to check every iteration, the impact on performance for one if statement will be so small that the natural inaccuracy in requestAnimationFrame timing will far outweigh the nanoseconds you *waste* in an if statement

Comment: @JaromandaX are you sure about this? setTimeout has always had a 1ms max precision, timing attacks like Spectre require nano seconds timing *measurements*. setTimeout is not at risk here and I don't think nobody added a "jitter" to it.

Comment: @Kaiido - according to release notes for browsers about a year ago, both major browsers (firefox and chrome) did so - not sure if they are still (edit: I was wrong)... however, setTimeout was never millisecond accurate anyway - so the point is, using setTimeout for precise millisecond timing is never going to be a solution

Comment: @Kaiido - sorry - my mistake, it was domhighrestimestamp that had the jitter added

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` is not the last thing to get called in the Event loop, quite at the contrary actually, in the [Event Loop model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model), *run the animation frame callbacks* is among the last things to get called.

So I'm not sure what you did, but using *setTimeout* should work just fine:

```js
let stopped = false;
const startTime = performance.now();
let rafTime;
let frame_id = requestAnimationFrame( loop );
setTimeout(() => {
  cancelAnimationFrame(frame_id);
  stopped = true;
  console.log( 'stopped' );
  console.log( "rAF loop ran for %sms", rafTime - startTime );
}, 2000);

function loop() {
  if( stopped ) { console.log( 'failed' ); }
  rafTime = performance.now();
  frame_id = requestAnimationFrame( loop );
}
```

An other solution, just as good since you probably need a delta-time in what you do in rAF is to check the timestamp passed to your callback. That's a really fast operation, don't worry about the perfs at all here.

```js
let startTime;
requestAnimationFrame( loop );
function loop( time ) {
  if( !startTime ) { startTime = time; }
  if( time - startTime >= 2000 ) {
    console.log( 'ran for %sms', time - startTime )
    return;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame( loop );
}
```

The one thing about this approach is that you'll know later on that the time elapsed, meaning you could be one frame late.
You could try to substract the frameRate from the duration yourself, but rAF rate is dependent on the monitor's refresh-rate, and hence hard to calculate.

But this can also be an advantage, since you will also be able to perform a last-frame rendering, often useful when doing animations so that the final call draws at the exact static position.

Now note that [Chrome has known issues](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1018120) with their way of calling rAF, maybe your code breaks because of something like that, maybe it breaks because of other logics, but without your code, all we can say is that *it should work*.